# How to add another RSU in the Heterogeneous example of Veins-lte

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm using Omnet++4.6 and Veins-LTE 1.3. I'm trying to modify the Heterogeneous example by adding another eNobeB (RSU). I added this in Highway.ned:

```
eNodeB2: eNodeB {@display("p=121,177;is=vl");}
server.pppg++ <--> Eth10G <--> eNodeB2.ppp;
```

and in omnetpp.ini:

```
**.eNodeB2.macCellId = 1
**.eNodeB2.macNodeId = 1
```

When I started with running the simulation of this example, there's no communication between the two eNobeB (RSU) and cars. But the communication between the first RSU and cars return when I delete this line from Highway.ned:

```
server.pppg++ <--> Eth10G <--> eNodeB2.ppp;
```

How can I adjust the code to allow the second RSU exchange messages?

[image]